# Running a test and REPL work differently

Tags: emacs, clojure, webdriver, cider

I found quite strange behavior in Clojure/Cider. When I try to execute the same expression in two ways (to run a test and run in REPL), I have different results.

Here is an expression:

```
  (with-chrome {} driver
    (start)
    (doto driver
      (go "http://localhost:3000")
      (wait-visible {:id :domain})
      (fill {:id :domain} "foo")
      (click {:id :login_button})
      (wait 5))
    (stop))
```

The first way is I wrapped it with `deftest`. The second one I copy and paste it in REPL. The difference is when I run the test the `click` command does not work at all. While the REPL scenario works as well.

Could somebody give me a tip? PS: I use `etaoin` library in example above.

Comment: It might help if you include the project.clj file in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason was I wrapped he whole code into DB transaction that locked tables due to TRUNCATE operation. That's why clicking on a button sent an ajax request that hanged forever.